# How do I create the percentage on this graph in svg?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to develop this chart in svg:

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3elaD.png)

```css
.circulo{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 35px solid pink;
  position: absolute;
top: 10px;
    left: 57px; 
}

svg{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 162px;
}
circle{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 !important;
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    r: 140;
    cy: 0;
    cx: 176;
    stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="360" height="360" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <circle r="89.85699" cy="50" cx="50" stroke-width="50" stroke="#69aff4" fill="none" style="stroke-dashoffset: 360;"></circle> 
</svg>
```

But I'm not able to give the percentage.

I've tried using the **stroke-dashoffset** and **stroke-dasharray** and I couldn't.

How can I do this?

Comment: You won't be able to use `stroke-dashoffset` to partially stroke the circle if you're also using the `stroke-dasharray` for the little hashes. One approach would be to use a solid stroke, and then apply a mask to create the hashing. Then you can use the `dashoffset` technique for stroking only part of the circle

Comment: percentage of what, though? (the SVG looks like it's a full circle with a bad `viewBox`: what part of your code is supposed to tie into percentages?)

Comment: Adding to @Sean comment: here's a tutorial using `stroke-dashoffset` and `stroke-dasharray` [Building a Progress Ring, Quickly](https://css-tricks.com/building-progress-ring-quickly/), which also shows Sean's point. You will need to use some *pie-chart* mechanism to get a 'dashed' version, tutorial: [A simple pie chart in SVG](https://medium.com/hackernoon/a-simple-pie-chart-in-svg-dbdd653b6936) (simplest, smartest I have found to date). You will need to add some `offset` per 'piece-of-pie' to create gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve using Sean's idea. Tks man!

```
<svg class="svg2" width="360" height="360" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="circle2" r="140" cy="0" cx="176" stroke-width="50" stroke="red" fill="none" style="stroke-dashoffset: 360;"></circle> 
</svg>
<svg class="svg1" width="360" height="360" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle class="circle1" r="140" cy="0" cx="176" stroke-width="50" stroke="white" fill="none" style="stroke-dashoffset: 360;"></circle> 
</svg>



.svg1{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 162px;
}
.circle1{
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 !important;
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    stroke-width: 40px;
}

.svg2{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    height: 162px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.circle2{
    stroke-dashoffset: 90 !important;
    stroke-dasharray: 440;
    stroke-width: 38px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/sauloduarte/pen/xxVZOKL